# Android - can't execute simple cd in emulator

Tags: java, android, shell, command, emulation

- I have an emulator which I rooted (although I'm not sure it's
  relevant)
- I'm trying to build a root app for my thesis that when a button is
  pressed, it tries to find a database file.
- I'm up to the point that I'm trying to execute shell commands from
  within the app (java code), but all I can do is `ls`.
- When I try to `cd` to another folder, it doesn't work. After the `cd`
  I execute `pwd`or `ls` which still give results for `/`.
- Below is the pertinent portion of my code

  ```
  Button btn_read = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
      btn_read.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
              /*String s;

              try {
                  Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ls -al");
                  p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("adb shell");
                  p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cd data/data");

                  BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new
                          InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

                  BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new
                          InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));

                  // read the output from the command
                  Log.d("ReadDB", "Here is the standard output of the command:\n");
                  while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
                      Log.d("ReadDB", s);
                  }

                  // read any errors from the attempted command
                  Log.d("ReadDB", "Here is the standard error of the command (if any):\n");
                  while ((s = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
                      Log.d("ReadDB", s);
                  }

                  System.exit(0);
              }
              catch (IOException e) {
                  Log.d("ReadDB", "Exception happened - here's what I know: ");
                  e.printStackTrace();
                  System.exit(-1);
              }*/

              executeCommand(new String[] {
                  "sh", "-c", "ls -l"
              });
              /*executeCommand(new String[] {
                  "sh", "-c", "cd /mnt"
              });*/
              executeCommand(new String[] {
                  "sh", "-c", "ls -l data/data"
              });
              executeCommand(new String[] {
                  "sh", "-c", "pwd"
              });
          }
      });
  }

  private static void executeCommand(String[] commands) {
      Process p;
      try {
          p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commands);
          p.waitFor();
          BufferedReader reader =
                  new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

          String line = "";
          while ((line = reader.readLine())!= null) {
              Log.d("ReadDB", line + "\n");
          }
          Log.d("ReadDB", "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");

      } catch (Exception e) {
          Log.d("ReadDB", "Exception occured");
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
  }
  ```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

The commands will be running in *separate [subshells](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/SubShell)*, so that is not possible. What *should* work:

```
executeCommand(new String[] {
    "sh", "-c", "cd /mnt && some other command"
});
```